# Dynamically check if cell values exist more than once

Tags: vba, excel

I have a row of data with headers, and the same headers can appear `n` number of times. I need to loop over the headers in VBA, check if each one exists more than once in the whole row, and if so, add a string at the end of each one.

```
HEADER 1 HEADER 2 HEADER 3 HEADER 1 HEADER 2 HEADER 3
```

and the result should be after looping (something like:

```
HEADER 1 OLD HEADER 2 OLD HEADER 3 OLD HEADER 1 NEW HEADER 2 NEW HEADER 3 NEW
```

I know i need to loop over the cells, but then the logic escapes me

```
For i = 1 to lastCol
    If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = "HEADER 1" Then
         headerCount = headerCount + 1
    End if
Next i
```

The logic after the for loop escapes me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best approach, but you could loop through the list twice and compare. If you have a lot of headers, this may be slow.

```
For i = 1 to lastCol - 1
    numDuplicates = 0
    for j = i + 1 to lastCol
        if ws.Cells(1,i) = ws.Cells(1,j) then
            numDuplicates = numDuplicates + 1
            ws.Cells(1,j) = ws.Cells(1,j) & " " & numDuplicates
        end if
    next j
next i
```

Something like that? This retains the original header and then marks the duplicates with a 1, 2, ...

Comment: Cool, this would work. My brain is not letting me think of another way, so this might have to be it. Why lastCol - 1? Yeah, I will definitely have multiple duplicate values, i would need to add a counter to each one somehow, i.e. OLD 1, OLD 2, etc..

Comment: The reason for that is because you comparing what is in `i` with what is in `i+1`. I just edited to start the `j` loop from that spot. I keep improving the code as I think about it. :)

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the multiple duplicates.

Comment: Bam, nice! This makes sense, thanks. I somehow could not think of looping twice today

Comment: Glad I could help.